# Regularly corrupted Git repository stored on Dropbox

Tags: git, corruption, corrupt

On my machine I have a lot of different Git repositories but among them there is one special. It is taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/AlekseyBuzmakov/SPbPU-BCI-template) and cloned to Dropbox as bare repository. Then in Dropbox a new branch is created and this branch is modified in other folder (ROOT in this text) outside the Dropbox.

The problem is that the repository in ROOT becomes frequently corrupted, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455179/badly-corrupted-git-repository). Moreover, it can be good in the evening and bad in the morning, or good now and bad in twp hours. During this time it is not necessary to even do anything in the ROOT. For example I can run `git status`, everything is fine, and then I do something different outside of the ROOT. Then when I return to ROOT, `git status` fails.

I can clone DROPBOX to ROOT_1, when it fails, I clone DROPBOX to ROOT_2, it fails, I clone DROPBOX to ROOT_3, it fails and so on. Since I have not removed ROOT_1,ROOT_2,..., it is unlikely that my disk is corrupted since every new cloning is placed in other physical space. Moreover, with other Git repos I have never had similar problems.

Finally, I should also mention that removing a set of images from the modifying branch, increased the average time needed for corruption.

I am stuck with that and appreciate any help: diagnostic, workaround, etc.

I am using Ubuntu 17.10, 64bit, Git version 2.14.1.

**UPD:** I have removed the link to dropbox and have used bitbucket for a while. It was fine and I thought that it was indeed because of Dropbox. Unfortunately, when I have corrected some figures in the repo, I get the same error as before. So even though dropbox seems to influence the frequencies it is not the only reason for the corruption :(

Comment: Dropbox and git don't play well together. Just choose one

Comment: Use bitbucket, or another such service, to host your git repos. Bitbucket is free for private repos.

Comment: @DavidRawson, yes, dropbox does not ensure a good concurrent access. However, in my case there is never concurrent access. Moreover DROPBOX repo is always correct, the problem appears only in ROOT repo, that is outside of the folder and the corruption happen without any interaction with DROPBOX repo.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, thank you for reference to Bitbucket, I should give a try to it. However, the problem appears outside of the Dropbox.